# using ObjectAnimation to move an image from left to right

Tags: android, android-animation

i have an image and i animate it to move from left to right according to the layout width().it worked but not in the first time that i open my activity,only after i pushed back from another activity -the animation started.
here is the relevant piece in my code:

```
protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
    sMineAnimatior();

}

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


}
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();


}

public void sMineAnimatior(){
    ObjectAnimator   bombAnim=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bombV,"translationX",0,mainLayout.getWidth());
    bombAnim.setDuration(5000);
    bombAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    bombAnim.setTarget(bombV);
    bombAnim.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `mainLayout.getWidth()` returns 0, because the view hasn't been measured yet. Use [one of the techniques described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/242838) to make sure you don't call too early.